# Validating angular 1.x input checkbox

Tags: angularjs, selenium, webdriver

I have the following angular 1.x checkbox:

```
<input
 type="checkbox"
 name="fooName"
 id="fooId"
 ng-model="false"
 >
```

Suppose I do the following in jQuery:

```
$("#fooId").val()
```

I always get "on". This is the same result I get from webdriver io.

To reiterate my question:

- How do I get the value from a checkbox input?
- If there is no way to extract that, is there any other way to validate this from selenium or webdriver io??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTML Chekbox, we should check it checked/unchecked status, rather than its value. Its value never change no matter it checked or unchecked.

For example
  `<input type="checkbox" name="aa" value="true">`, `$("#fooId").val()` will always return `"true"` no matter you check it or not.

If the check has no attribute `value`, like `<input type="checkbox" name="aa">`, you will always get `"on"` when call  `$("#fooId").val()`

We should check its check status as following:

```
driver.findElement(By.css('#fooId')).isSelected();
```

Comment: I suppose I have no choice but to use ng-model with value attribute at the same time.